# Lost message when stoping and restarting Embedded ActiveMQ

Tags: scala, apache, jms, activemq-classic

Hi I am trying to write a test-case for implementing fail over support for activeMQ.

Here is the code

```
val brokerA = createBroker("A")
brokerA.start
val failoverUrl = s"failover:(vm://BrokerA?create=false)" +
s"?randomize=false&maxReconnectAttempts=-1&reconnectSupported=true"


val cFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(failoverUrl)
val qConnection = getQueueConnection
val session = createQueueSession(qConnection)

private def totalReadMessagesCount(queueReceiver: QueueReceiver) = {
val messages = Iterator.continually(Option(queueReceiver.receive(2000))).takeWhile(_.isDefined).flatten.toSeq
messages.size
}

private def getReceiver = {
val queueConnection = getQueueConnection
queueConnection.start()
val queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
val queueReceiver = createQueueReceiver(queueSession, brokerA.getBrokerName)
queueReceiver
}

def getQueueConnection =cFactory.createQueueConnection("admin", "")

def createBroker(name:String) = {
val broker = new BrokerService()
val adaptor = new KahaDBPersistenceAdapter()
broker.setBrokerName("Broker" + name)
broker.addConnector(getBrokerUrl)
broker.setPersistent(true)
broker.setUseJmx(false)
broker.setUseShutdownHook(false)
broker
}

def getBrokerUrl =  "tcp://localhost:0"


val queueReceiver: QueueReceiver = getReceiver
val messageCount = 500
(1 to messageCount) map {count =>
  //Calling method to send message to ActiveMQ
  if(count == 200){
    brokerA.stop()
    brokerA.waitUntilStopped()
    brokerA.start(true)
  }
}
val totalCount = totalReadMessagesCount(queueReceiver)
println(s"Read ${totalCount} messages")
assert(totalCount == messageCount)
```

I am able to reconnect with activeMQ after restart but `totalCount` is displaying 300 instead of 500. It seems previous messages are lost. However when I run same scenario in non-embedded mode. I am able to get all messages.

Please help me how can I prevent to loose any message while restarting embedded active mq.

Comment: You need to have 2(two) instances of activeMQ to test the failover. The failover means that if a client can't talk to given server it will try next one from the list of servers in the connection string. You have only one server in your connection string. See the documentation here: http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to set persistent to true, i don't know scala but here is java code

```
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    //broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
    broker.addConnector("stomp://localhost:61613");
    broker.addConnector("vm://localhost");
    PersistenceAdapter persistenceAdapter = new KahaDBPersistenceAdapter();
    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "kaha");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    persistenceAdapter.setDirectory(dir);
    broker.setPersistenceAdapter(persistenceAdapter);
    broker.setPersistent(true);
    return broker;
}
```

Comment: I just updated my example. I have made persistent to true and added KahaDB. But Now I am getting 305 in count. Any suggestion?

Comment: You have created an instance of KahaDBPersistenceAdapter but you do not set it up to the broker no ?? Like this  broker.setPersistenceAdapter(adaptor);